# st_segmentize not giving exact results

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I would expect each segment length (ST_Length) in this query to be exactly or close to 403 meters. Why do these distances vary?

```
SELECT n,
       ST_SRID(ST_LineSubstring(ST_LineSubstring(the_geom, 403.00*n/length,
         LEAST(403.00*(n+1)/length, 1.0)), 0.0, 1 )::GEOGRAPHY ),
       ST_LineSubstring(the_geom, 403.00*n/length,
         LEAST(403.00*(n+1)/length, 1.0)) AS the_geom,
       ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(ST_LineSubstring(the_geom, 403.00*n/length,
         LEAST(403.00*(n+1)/length, 1.0)), 0.0, 1 )::GEOGRAPHY )
FROM (
  SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_LineMerge('MULTILINESTRING((-81.2190071919865 34.1247822557825,-81.2155187121759 34.1240070380468,-81.212934653057 34.1231026173552,-81.2110612101958 34.1223273996195,
                                                     -81.2091231658566 34.121099971538,-81.2078311362971 34.1202601523243,-81.2053762801341 34.1192265286768,-81.2019524018015 34.1174176872935,
                                                     -81.1980763131231 34.1151566355644,-81.1940710214888 34.1129601853133,-81.1920683756716 34.1116681557539,-81.1912285564579 34.1092779010689,
                                                     -81.1897427224646 34.1046265946548,-81.1883214899491 34.1008797089323,-81.1872232648236 34.0970036202539,-81.181473733284 34.113735403049,
                                                     -81.1851560175285 34.1222627981415,-81.1903887372443 34.1343432745225,-81.1871586633456 34.1415140385775))')::geography, 403.00)::geometry AS the_geom,
         ST_Length(geom::geography) AS length    
  FROM public."ticket_subdivide_lineTesting"
) AS t
CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,10000) AS n
WHERE n*403.00/length < 1 --limit 1
```

Comment: the length is computed using the `geom` field from `public."ticket_subdivide_lineTesting` but the operations occurs on the manually create `the_geom` field, which is likely of another length

Comment: this?: ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(ST_LineSubstring(the_geom, 403.00*n/length,
         LEAST(403.00*(n+1)/length, 1.0)), 0.0, 1 )::GEOGRAPHY )

Comment: no, `ST_Length(geom::geography) AS length  ` (5 lines from the bottom)

Comment: I don't follow you on that. 'length' is the total length of the line and is just used in the st_linesubstring function. It should be the same across the board, correct?

Comment: yes, but in the code you are not computing the manually specified line length but of a geometry out of a table that is not used anywhere else. (likely a typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by `st_linesubstring`, not by `st_segmentize`.

You are computing the line substring using the data in lat-long 4326. The computed fractions in `st_linesubstring` are applied using the line length in the projection unit, so in degrees. For example, should you cut the original line in 10, each substring will be `1/10 * length in degrees`.

Since a degree corresponds to a different length in meter in the X or Y axis, and the length of a degree of longitude depends on the latitude, this length is meaningless.

Then, you convert these substring to `geography` in order to get the segment length in meters. The calculation takes into account the latitude/longitude of each vertex and returns the true distance, which is now different for each segment.

To overcome this, you could first project your data to a projection in meters, and that is suitable to your region to reduce distortion (UTM for example).